# Leak in this method

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, core-foundation

Leak instruments shows number of leaked `NSCFData` objects and stack trace apparently contains the following method at the end of the boundary of my app methods.

```
NSData* SAKeychainGetValue(NSString *key)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = SAGetKeychainSearchDictionary(key);
    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

    CFDataRef value = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, (CFTypeRef *)&value);
    if (status != errSecSuccess && status != errSecItemNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to get key %@ with error %ld.", key, (long)status);
    }
    return (__bridge NSData*)value;
}
```

But I can't see what is wrong with this method to leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `__bridge_transfer` instead of `__bridge` in `(__bridge NSData*)value`.

The value return from `SecItemCopyMatching` method (copy means the value returns should be released in apple naming convention) should be released, so you should transfer the ownership to ARC.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the static analyser to solve issues like this `CMD+Shift+B` is the default shortcut

But you're mixing your bridges up

```
NSData* SAKeychainGetValue(NSString *key)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = SAGetKeychainSearchDictionary(key);
    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

    CFDataRef value = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, (CFTypeRef *)&value);
    if (status != errSecSuccess && status != errSecItemNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to get key %@ with error %ld.", key, (long)status);
    }
    return (__bridge_transfer NSData*)value;
}
```

You could also probably just use `NSData` directly:

```
    NSData *value = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, (CFTypeRef *)&value);
    ...
    return value;
```